# When FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage is enabled, callbacks in Webview stop working

Tags: flutter, firebase, webview, push

When developing an application that uses both PUSH notifications and WebView at the same time, there was a problem that after calling FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage, StreamSubscription calls in WebView stop working.
There is a registered error with the same meaning on [GitHub](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/939?ysclid=lg56she6pa128678054), but there is no movement on it. Can you tell me what else you can do?

Example code:

```
late StreamSubscription<String> _onUrlChanged;
....
Future main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
....
}
@override
void initState() {
...
_onUrlChanged = flutterWebViewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
  print("URL: $url");
});
...
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  WebviewScaffold(
      ignoreSSLErrors: true,
      url: selectedUrl,
      javascriptChannels: jsChannels,
      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Widget WebView'),
      ),
      withZoom: true,
      withLocalStorage: true,
      hidden: false,
      initialChild: Container(
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        child: const Center(
          child: Text('loading...'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

As soon as I remove the line FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
everything starts working right away

Comment: Hi ! Did you find a solution ? I have the same error

Comment: I couldn't fix it. I stopped at the fact that this is an incompatibility of modules. Replaced the flutter_webview_plugin_ios_android module with webview_flutter